# how to use nfs storage in crunchydata postgres operator

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, nfs, pgo

I am trying out the CrunchyData postgres-operator(Helm) with the [NFS Helm](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner) chart. And I am unable to create the Cluster with NFS. The following configuration is performed:

Installed [NFS helm](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner) chart Repo

```
helm install nfs-abc stable/nfs-server-provisioner
```

Set the postgres storage values [Doc](https://crunchydata.github.io/postgres-operator/stable/installation/configuration/#_storage_configuration)

```
backrest_storage: 'nfsstorage'
backup_storage: 'nfsstorage'
primary_storage: 'nfsstorage'
replica_storage: 'nfsstorage'
```

Set the storage configuration [Doc](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/crunchy-postgres-containers/2.3.0/installation-guide/storage-configuration/)

```
export CCP_SECURITY_CONTEXT='"supplementalGroups": [65534]'
export CCP_STORAGE_PATH=/nfsfileshare
export CCP_NFS_IP=data-nfs-dravoka-nfs-server-provisioner-0.default.svc.cluster.local
export CCP_STORAGE_MODE=ReadWriteMany
export CCP_STORAGE_CAPACITY=400M
```

Created PGO cluster

```
pgo create cluster -n pgo dravoka --storage-config='nfsstorage' --pgbackrest-storage-config='nfsstorage' --pvc-size='2Gi'
```

PVC describe:

```
kubectl describe -n pgo pvc dravoka
Name:          dravoka
Namespace:     pgo
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        pg-cluster=dravoka
               pgremove=true
               vendor=crunchydata
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                    From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                   ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  112s (x10 over 7m45s)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "standard": invalid AccessModes [ReadWriteMany]: only AccessModes [ReadWriteOnce ReadOnlyMany] are supported
```

Pod Describe:

```
kubectl describe -n pgo pod dravoka-backrest-shared-repo-9fdd77886-j2mjv
Name:           dravoka-backrest-shared-repo-9fdd77886-j2mjv
Namespace:      pgo
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         name=dravoka-backrest-shared-repo
                pg-cluster=dravoka
                pg-pod-anti-affinity=preferred
                pgo-backrest-repo=true
                pod-template-hash=9fdd77886
                service-name=dravoka-backrest-shared-repo
                vendor=crunchydata
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/dravoka-backrest-shared-repo-9fdd77886
Containers:
  database:
    Image:      registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/pgo-backrest-repo:centos7-4.4.1
    Port:       2022/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Requests:
      memory:  48Mi
    Environment:
      PGBACKREST_STANZA:           db
      SSHD_PORT:                   2022
      PGBACKREST_DB_PATH:          /pgdata/dravoka
      PGBACKREST_REPO_PATH:        /backrestrepo/dravoka-backrest-shared-repo
      PGBACKREST_PG1_PORT:         5432
      PGBACKREST_LOG_PATH:         /tmp
      PGBACKREST_PG1_SOCKET_PATH:  /tmp
      PGBACKREST_DB_HOST:          dravoka
    Mounts:
      /backrestrepo from backrestrepo (rw)
      /sshd from sshd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  sshd:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  dravoka-backrest-repo-config
    Optional:    false
  backrestrepo:
    Type:        PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:   dravoka-pgbr-repo
    ReadOnly:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  76s (x7 over 9m58s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
```

Am I missing something that too is configured or doing something wrong? my purpose is to use NFS as postgres storage. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "standard": invalid
> AccessModes [ReadWriteMany]: only AccessModes [ReadWriteOnce
> ReadOnlyMany] are supported

So here is the root cause of the problem. You are provisioning the pvc using storage class that does not support the AccessModes that you want i.e. `ReadWriteMany`

Looking at the [doc](https://crunchydata.github.io/postgres-operator/stable/installation/configuration/#example-storage-configuration), seems like you have having this configuration

```
storage3_name: 'nfsstorage'
storage3_access_mode: 'ReadWriteMany'
storage3_size: '1G'
storage3_type: 'create'
storage3_supplemental_groups: 65534
```

Where the `storage3_access_mode` is saying that the access_mode is `ReadWriteMany` but this is not supported.

Please try to change it to `ReadWriteOnce`

---

Anw, Postgres requires block storage to work so even when you get the NFS setup right, your Postgres cluster will not run anyway. More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51725912/8673695)

Comment: PostgreSQL requires a file system, no block storage. NFS will do, but I heard many discouraging voices concerning the reliability of Linux' implementation.

Comment: Well, at least I cannot get it to work on NFS every single time. So yeah, just some additional information for reference :)

Comment: I tried by putting `nfs` as you said, but I am getting an error `"time="2020-09-16T06:40:46Z" level=error msg="Error in pgoconfig: check pgo.yaml: PrimaryStorage setting is invalid: \"nfs\" is not defined" func="internal/apiserver.Initialize()" file="internal/apiserver/root.go:134" version=4.4.1`

Comment: Looking at the example here: https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/blob/master/conf/postgres-operator/pgo.yaml#L46-L50.

I think you should put back `nfsstorage`. And update the `AccessMode` to `ReadWriteOnce`. I will update my answer.